# Is WB going to be opting-in to the new editor?

Tags: discussion

I noticed that SE is testing out a new rich text editor, similar to the one used by Reddit.

Will the beta be available in Worldbuilding, or will we need to wait until it gets out of testing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From what I can read in this [featured Meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/360033/644344)

> This is part of a multi-part test that will look something like this:
>
> - **Initial release on Teams with feedback from highly-engaged users (e.g. Moderators)** (Completed Summer 2020). The goal of this was to get feedback and get a good idea of how much we need to change the editor so that it will work for our public platform community. This allowed us to test many (though not all) of the features with a small group of people without impacting the public site.
> - **Testing on MSE and MSO through an opt-in alpha test.** The goal here is to further refine and identify solutions that will help the new editor be openly adopted by users, primarily active members of the community.
> - **Usability testing sessions with users of several different experience levels.** The goal here is to make sure that the features and UX we create after responding to our highly-engaged users is still transparent to others. We’ll watch how users of varying experience levels interact with the editor to identify and make additional improvements with the goal of an intuitive user experience that has sufficient guidance where needed.
>
> As to a timeline, this is expected to take a while to work through. One of the benefits of the alpha test is that people can enable and disable it as they wish. For the rest of 2021 Q1, our plan is to leave the test running so that y’all can try it out in a more long-term way if you wish. While we’ll be fixing major bugs, we won’t be prioritizing new features or adjustments until we start digging into your feedback from this test and the feedback from the usability sessions in the second quarter of 2021.See a bit more on this in the giving feedback section below.
>
> Assuming these tests go well and we find solutions that make post creation and editing easier than the current system, we’ll move into a gradual rollout phase, starting again with MSE and MSO and then to the sites with standard editing tools, reserving the sites with specialized editor add-ons for the end so that we can make sure that their tools work correctly upon launch.

I seem to understand there won't be a beta on Worldbuilding.

Comment: Thanks for the information.